# How to display the array in structured format?

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm new to c# programming, I had coded in c#(winforms) to get the output as: if an Item in the list box is clicked then the items should be displayed in the text box ,i had coded but its little bit hectic to implement to go further.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TextBox[] tb = new TextBox[5];
    TextBox[] t = new TextBox[5];
    TextBox[] t1 = new TextBox[5];
    int[] tblist = new int[5];


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tb[0] = new TextBox();
        tb[1] = new TextBox();
        tb[2] = new TextBox();
        tb[3] = new TextBox();
        tb[4] = new TextBox();
        t[0] = new TextBox();
        t[1] = new TextBox();
        t[2] = new TextBox();
        t[3] = new TextBox();
        t[4] = new TextBox();
        t1[0] = new TextBox();
        t1[1] = new TextBox();
        t1[2] = new TextBox();
        t1[3] = new TextBox();
        t1[4] = new TextBox();

    } //how can I simplify this by not assigning new to every textbox that i had created
```

// this button click is used to save items in the textbox in the listbox selected item
here how can we minimize the code : listbox selected  index differs but the functions remains the same..

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            tb[0].Text = textBox1.Text;
            tb[1].Text = textBox2.Text;
            tb[2].Text = textBox3.Text;
            tb[3].Text = textBox4.Text;
            tb[4].Text = textBox5.Text;
        }
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            t[0].Text = textBox1.Text;
            t[1].Text = textBox2.Text;
            t[2].Text = textBox3.Text;
            t[3].Text = textBox4.Text;
            t[4].Text = textBox5.Text;
        }
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            t1[0].Text = textBox1.Text;
            t1[1].Text = textBox2.Text;
            t1[2].Text = textBox3.Text;
            t1[3].Text = textBox4.Text;
            t1[4].Text = textBox5.Text;
        }
    }
```

//here an item is clicked in the list box., so then items in the text box can be store in the listbox selected index

```
    private void listBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {

             textBox1.Text = tb[0].Text;
            textBox2.Text = tb[1].Text;
            textBox3.Text = tb[2].Text;
            textBox4.Text = tb[3].Text;
            textBox5.Text = tb[4].Text;
        }

       if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {   textBox1.Text = t[0].Text;
            textBox2.Text = t[1].Text;
            textBox3.Text = t[2].Text;
            textBox4.Text = t[3].Text;
            textBox5.Text = t[4].Text;
        }
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            textBox1.Text = t1[0].Text;
            textBox2.Text = t1[1].Text;
            textBox3.Text = t1[2].Text;
            textBox4.Text = t1[3].Text;
            textBox5.Text = t1[4].Text;
        }
    `
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `for` loop for your arrays.

```
for(var i = 0; i < tb.Length; i++)
{
    tb[i] = new TextBox();
    t[i] = new TextBox();
    t1[i] = new TextBox();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet from code that I use.

Load your values into `DataTables`
and add a `tableLayoutPanel` to the form where you want the textboxes to go.

Call ***SetTextboxes*** function with `datatable` (or you can send your `list` here, just change the parameters and loop a little.

This will dynamically add textboxes to your form very quickly.

```
class SurroundingClass
{
    private void SetTextboxes(datatable DT)
    {
        //Clear the previous textboxes
        pnlLayoutExpenses.Controls.clear();
       //loop through table and create new textboxes
        foreach (DataRow row in DT.Rows)
            formAddTextbox(row("dataTableColumnWhichHoldsTextboxText"));
    }



    private void formAddTextbox(string fieldname)
    {

        Integer elementCount = 0;

        TextBox txtYourField = new TextBox();
        txtYourField.Width = 100;
        txtYourField.Height = 20;
        //txtYourField.ReadOnly = true;
        txtYourField.Text = fieldname;
        txtYourField.tag = elementCount; 


        // Use tableLayoutPanel
        pnlLayoutExpenses.SetCellPosition(txtType, new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, elementCount));

        pnlLayoutExpenses.Controls.Add(txtType);
    }
}
```